# Cannot add fit params to RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, xgboost

Trying to run the following RandomizedSearchCV...However, it only works when I exclude `eval_metric`, `early_stopping` and `eval_set` from the fit params.

```
param_grid = {
        'xgb__silent': [False],
        'xgb__max_depth': [3, 5, 6, 8],
        'xgb__subsample': [0.5],
        'xgb__learning_rate': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
        'xgb__colsample_bytree': [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0],
        'xgb__colsample_bylevel': [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0],
        'xgb__min_child_weight': [0.5, 1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 10.0],
        'xgb__gamma': [0, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0],
        'xgb__reg_lambda': [0.1, 1.0, 5.0, 10.0, 50.0, 100.0],
        'xgb__n_estimators': [100, 250, 500]}

fit_params = {
              #'xgb__eval_metric': ['mlogloss'],
              #'xgb__early_stopping_rounds': [10],
              #'xgb__eval_set': [(val_tfidf, y_val)],
              'xgb__sample_weight': X_train['weights'].to_numpy()}

if __name__ == "__main__":

    scoring = {'f1': 'f1_macro', 'brier': 'brier_score_loss', 
               'logloss': 'neg_log_loss'}

    rs_clf = RandomizedSearchCV(xgb_pipe, param_grid, n_iter=30,
                                n_jobs=-1, verbose=2, cv=2,
                                scoring=scoring, 
                                refit='logloss', 
                                random_state=42)

    print("Randomized search..")
    rs_clf.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
    print("Randomized search time:")

    best_score = rs_clf.best_score_
    best_params = rs_clf.best_params_
    print("Best score: {}".format(best_score))
    print("Best params: ")
    for param_name in sorted(best_params.keys()):
        print('%s: %r' % (param_name, best_params[param_name]))
```

If the fit params values are not passed as lists with a single index, like this:

```
fit_params = {'xgb__eval_metric': ['mlogloss'],
              'xgb__early_stopping_rounds': [10],
              'xgb__eval_set': [(val_tfidf, y_val)],
              'xgb__sample_weight': [X_train['weights'].to_numpy()]}
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples
```

After this though, I get a different error:

```
Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I can't figure out why it's not working, or where it's getting stuck. Is there just generally a problem with trying to add fit params with RandomizedSearchCV?

EDIT: 
Okay, I feel kind of silly. I changed the objective from `multi:softprob` to `multi:softmax` and it works. It was outputting 3 probabilities with the softprob function and this was causing an error for the eval loss (it expects a single value). I also had to change the fit params dict and have `early_stopping_rounds` as an int and not a list... (now it works without having to place everything in a single index list, and it's not throwing the earlier error). My code was additionally breaking with the `brier_score_loss` because I have more than two classes. Full solution:

```
class ItemSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
    def fit(self, x, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, data_dict):
        return data_dict[self.key]

# create dense matrices for randomgridsearchcv
tfidf_pipe = Pipeline([
    ('text', ItemSelector(key='clean_text')),
    ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(max_features=80000, ngram_range=(1,3))),
    ('svd', TruncatedSVD(algorithm='randomized', random_state=42, n_components=300))
])

features_pipe = Pipeline([
    ('select', ItemSelector(key=['rating', 'aws_neg', 'aws_pos', 'aws_mix', 'char_count',
                                   'vadar_pos', 'vadar_neg', 'vadar_neu', 'tb_sentiment']))])
feature_union_pipe = FeatureUnion([   
    ('tfidf', tfidf_pipe),
    ('features', features_pipe)
])

model = XGBClassifier(objective='multi:softmax', num_class=3)

xgb_pipe = Pipeline([
    ('all_features', feature_union_pipe),
    ('xgb', model)
])

train_tfidf = feature_union_pipe.fit_transform(X_train)
val_tfidf = feature_union_pipe.transform(X_val)

param_grid = {
        'xgb__model': [model],
        'xgb__silent': [False],
        'xgb__max_depth': [3, 5, 6, 8],
        'xgb__subsample': [0.5],
        'xgb__learning_rate': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
        'xgb__colsample_bytree': [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0],
        'xgb__colsample_bylevel': [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0],
        'xgb__min_child_weight': [0.5, 1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 10.0],
        'xgb__gamma': [0, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0],
        'xgb__reg_lambda': [0.1, 1.0, 5.0, 10.0, 50.0, 100.0],
        'xgb__n_estimators': [100, 250, 500]}

fit_params = {'xgb__eval_metric': ['mlogloss'],
              'xgb__early_stopping_rounds': 10,
              'xgb__eval_set': [(val_tfidf, y_val)],
              'xgb__sample_weight': X_train['weights'].to_numpy()}

if __name__ == "__main__":

    scoring = {'f1': 'f1_macro', 'logloss': 'neg_log_loss'}

    rs_clf = RandomizedSearchCV(xgb_pipe, param_grid, n_iter=1,
                                n_jobs=-1, verbose=2, cv=2,
                                scoring=scoring, 
                                refit='logloss', 
                                random_state=42)

    print("Randomized search..")
    rs_clf.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
    print("Randomized search time:")

    best_score = rs_clf.best_score_
    best_params = rs_clf.best_params_
    print("Best score: {}".format(best_score))
    print("Best params: ")
    for param_name in sorted(best_params.keys()):
        print('%s: %r' % (param_name, best_params[param_name]))
```

Comment: run this line `assert X_train.shape[0] == y_train.shape[0]`. does the assertion fail?

Comment: No, it doesn't `(X_train shape: (143095, 43), y_train shape: (143095,)`